# Maximum size of response iOS JSON Parser can handle

Tags: ios, json, max

What is the maximum size of http response that most common iOS parser (like JSONKit and Apple JSON parser) can handle.
Also what is the maximum depth.

Thank you.

Comment: It would be better if you could pass the json data using pagination to your iOS device, as it will reduce the load on device and also the waiting time.

Comment: @RenoJones :Ok I need to know what would be proper size for each page .Rough estimation .a page with to much data can be bigger than 2 or 3 of pages with less data .so the size is the criterion

Comment: Depends upon the json size, if it is around 100KB (with 20-25 as its PageSize) then try to restrict to 25 else if it is 100KB (with 100+pagesize) then try to set pageSize to 100, but I would say play around 100Kbs of json (or below), but not much.